# How to use 2 ForeignKey filters one by one in 1 view - Django?

Tags: python, django

Hello and thank your for your answer:

My Taks: Show article, show 3 questions (related to this article), show 3 answer for each queston (related to these questions). Like a coomon test page.

**My models:**

```
class Step(models.Model):  #Main article
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    annotation = models.TextField()
    main_text = models.TextField()   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model): #Questios related to Article.
    step = models.ForeignKey(Step, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default = "pages")
    question_text = models.TextField()
    question_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, help_text="английские буквы", blank=True, null=True)

class Answer(models.Model): #Answers related to Questions
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.TextField()
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    answer_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, help_text="английские буквы", blank=True, null=True)
```

**How it should works**

I use identificator in url, to show django which article it should show. Also it helps me to filtrs questions for this article. And then i should filted answers for each question, i have got previously. There are many articles, questions and answers, so you can't use objects().all.

```
url(r'^question(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)$', 'bakot.views.question', name='question'), #urls.py

def question(request, question_id):
    stepfields = get_object_or_404(Step, id = question_id) #get an article
    questionship = Question.objects.filter(step_id = question_id) #get questions, related to this article.
    answership = questionship.prefetch_related().all #this is doesn't work. And i couldn't use coommon filter, as i don't know id for them. Or i could set ID and it will show the same answers for 3 questions.        
    context = {
        "stepfieldst" : stepfields,
        "questionship" : questionship,
        "answership" : answership,
    }
    return render(request, 'bakot/question.html', context)
```

How i show it in template: (the part with questions ans answers)

```
{% block question_area %}
  {% for question in questionship %}
  <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 test-remark">
    <legend><strong>{{ question.title }}&nbsp;</strong>{{ question.question_text }}</legend>

      <ul class="menu vertical">

        {% for answer in answership  %}
        <li>
          <ul class="menu test-answer-padding navigation_hover_link11">
            <li class="test-dot-padding"><input type="radio" name="{{ question.question_name }}" value="{{ answer.answer_name }}" id="pokemonRed" required></li>
            <li><label for="pokemonRed">{{ answer.choice_text }}</label>
          </ul>
        </li>

        {% endfor %}

      </ul>

  </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things I would do here to provide you the best solution.

First, you don't need to include `questionship` and `answership` in your context. Your template can get them via `stepfields.questions` and `question.answers`.

Next, to limit your list to 3, I would implement a template filter. This could be done using slices, like this:

```
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def limit_to_3(list, arg):
    return list[0:arg]
```

You could then, in your template, change your `{% for %}` loops to be this format:

```
{% for question in stepfieldst.questions|limit:3 %}
    {% for answer in question.answers|limit:3 %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Depending if your number of questions and answers per article are low enough that querying them all would be less burdensome than multiple queries, you could do something like this:

```
try:
    stepfieldst = Step.objects.select_related(questions__answers).filter(id = question_id)
except Step.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
```

This would select all related questions and answers in a single query.